# AspNet Set Focus() works but :focus style's not apply

Tags: css, asp.net, focus, setfocus

When a value is insert in a textbox I would like to focus a specific button on the page. 
I wrote this:

```
  Private Sub CalcolaImporto() Handles txtQnt.TextChanged
    Try
       //Some code

            btnAdd.Focus()
    Catch ex As Exception
        m_WriteLogEventi(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "Si è verificato un errore:", ex.ToString(), logLivello.Errore,,, True)

    End Try

End Sub
```

In fact it is onFocus because if I press Enter the instruction of the button stars.

This is scss rule

```
&.action {
    background-color: $verde;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    &:hover {
        background-color: lighten($verde,10%);
    }

    &:focus {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 $verde;
        box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 $verde;
        background-color: lighten($verde,10%) !important;
    }
```

}

However the style defined in the css (: focus) is not applied.
Why?
I would like to make it clear to the user that the button is focused

Answer (score 0):

Do you try these code:

```
button:focus {
  background: pink;
}
```